# Angular checkbox hack takes two clicks to show false

Tags: angular, checkbox

So I have a form dynamically populating with checkboxes. And a checkbox hack to overwrite the way the checkbox will look. Unfortunately it takes two clicks to make the checkbox appear as false. Another dev wrote the css so I'm not sure where this hack is from.

I have attached a plunkr to demonstrate:

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/N423v240CZvXshre

Comment: I don't know when I try to save, I get this error from plnkr: `Error saving plunk: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined` I could save after I forked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the line that says `checked="{{scProfile.Enabled}}"`, as it is not needed while you're using `ngModel`

**[Here is a fork of the plnkr to demonstrate](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/DkJiWBkT6Ckjj7sA)**

Comment: Thanks! this is the solution.

Comment: @iamcootis Glad to help. Please mark the solution as accepted with the green tick if you don't mind

Answer (score 0):

To above answer of @user184994, i would like to add if you want some automation script to pick up the checkbox status while running on your angular application its better to keep the checked attribute and not use ngModel

```
    //our root app component
import { Component, NgModule, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <form #form="ngForm" class="edit-path__form">

        <div class="edit-path__form-container">
            <div class="grey-value-bold"></div>
            <div class="edit-path__form-sctypes">
                <div *ngFor="let scProfile of Profiles; let rowIndex = index" class="path-template" >
                    <label class="grey-title" style="flex-grow: 1;margin-left: 15px;" for="checkbox_{{rowIndex}}">{{scProfile.Name}}</label>
                    <div class="checkbox" style="border-bottom: 1px solid;">
                        <input
                                type="checkbox"
                                id="checkbox_{{rowIndex}}"
                                checked="{{scProfile.Enabled=== 'false'? null:''}}"
                                name="{{scProfile.ID}}"                                
                        >
                        <label for="checkbox_{{rowIndex}}" style="float: left; margin-left: -20px;"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
    `,
})
export class App {
    name: string;
    Profiles: any;
    constructor() {
        this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;
        this.Profiles = [
        {Name: 'Alpha', ID: '1', Enabled: false},
        {Name: 'Beta', ID: '2', Enabled: false},
        {Name: 'Gamma', ID: '3', Enabled: false},
        {Name: 'Delta', ID: '4', Enabled: false},
        {Name: 'Zeta', ID: '5', Enabled: false},
        {Name: 'Rho', ID: '6', Enabled: false}
    ]
    }
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [App],
    bootstrap: [App],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: The checked property will still be set. Give it a try on that plunkr by printing `document.getElementById('checkbox_2').checked`

Answer (score 0):

```
Include this in your .ts file if its not already there. I had faced the same issue and I got it resolved after adding this line and import it from angular/core. 


  ***changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush***

Something like this:

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: '',
  styleUrls: [''],
  ***changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush***
})
```